# Finding a conjecture about the final decimal digit of the square of an integer and proving the result

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I am currently taking a discrete mathematics course. When learning about proof by cases, the following example is presented in the book:
[image]

I understand why we can express n as 10a+b. I do not understand how we can conclude that the final decimal digit of n^2 is the same as the final decimal digit of b^2. What is the logic and reasoning behind this conclusion.

Furthermore, I do not understand how we can so easily conclude that the final decimal digit of (10-b)^2 = 100-20b+b^2 OR how we can reduce our proof to six cases.

I would appreciate a more in-depth explanation, as the book has made several conclusions that I cannot see the reasoning behind. If I plug in values to these equivalences, they are accurate, but I do not understand the steps in reasoning taken here.

Comment: You have heard in the past that "*even times even is even*" and "*odd times even is even*" and so on, yes?  That we don't need to know exactly which even number it was multiplied where... the same thing is occurring here.  Note that $(10a+b)\times (10c+d) = \underbrace{10(10ac+ad+bc)}_{\text{all multiple of 10}} + bd$

Comment: > OR how we can reduce our proof to six cases.
Well, as I understand it, its more like reducing the proof to 10 cases, checking when final digit of n is 0 to 9. But as there are 4 common final digits in the squares like (1 and 9, both whose squares have the final digit as 1), the textbook reduces it to 6 cases.

Answer (score 1):

We're trying to investigate the decimal digits of $n^2$, where $n$ is some integer. Suppose the final decimal digit of $n$ is $b$. Then, as you mentioned, we can write $n = 10a +b$, since $n-b$ has a zero as its final digit and is thus a multiple of 10. Since we're interested in $n^2$, let's square both sides of that expression:

$$n^2 = (10a+b)^2 = 100a^2 + 20ab + b^2.$$ Note that the first two terms on the right hand side are multiples of 10. All multiples of 10 end with a zero digit, so when we add them to $b^2$, they won't change the final digit of $b^2$. Thus, the final decimal digit will just be the final decimal digit of $b^2$. $b$ is allowed to be any number from 0 to 9, so it remains to just try them all: $0^2 = 0, 1^2 = 1, 2^2 = 4, 3^2 = 9, 4^2 = 16, 5^2 = 25, 6^2 = 36, 7^2 = 49, 8^2 = 64, 9^2 = 81$. The final decimal digits of all of the above numbers, in order and removing and repetitions are $0,1,4,9,6,5$. Since these are all possible final decimal digits of $b^2$, they are also all possible final decimal digits of $n^2$, which is the theorem we wanted to prove.